# Is it possible to do a post request from browser URL

Tags: authentication, post, request, http-post

I have one site e.g. www.myfirstsite.com/myapp .

When I do login in this site I did extract the POST request of authentication  from the browser.

Is just a simple authentication (the authentication URL is different) process. 
and username and password in parameters

username = abc_user

password = 123456

and the complete URL is `www.anothersite.com/login?username=abc_user&password=123456`

When I do POST request using `Postman` I received expected result.

Is there any way (any script which I enter in URL) to do POST request from browser URL itself like GET Request to authenticate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your browser's URL bar, type

```
javascript:
```

and then paste the following

```
(function(){document.body.innerHTML='<form method="POST" action="http://www.myfirstsite.com/myapp"><input name="username" value="abc_user"/><input name="password" value="123456"/></form>';document.forms[0].submit()})();
```

It will insert a form with the required values in the page and then submit it.

The reason you have to type the `javascript:` manually, is that for security reasons, some browsers will strip it off if you paste the entire blob.

You can also create a bookmark with the contents below and use that.

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML='<form method="POST" action="http://www.myfirstsite.com/myapp"><input name="username" value="abc_user"/><input name="password" value="123456"/></form>';document.forms[0].submit()})();
```

Comment: Thanks @Robby, This is what I want :)