# java rest API post method gives HTTP 405 method not allowed

Tags: java, rest, maven

I am trying to persist a object to my database with JPA and through a RESTful api. When testing the post methods in postman, it works and it inserts the row succesfully in the DB. However when testing in a chrome it gives me a HTTP error - 405 method not allowed?

This is my method

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("{description}/{name}")
public Response postHobby(
        @PathParam("description") String description,
        @PathParam("name") String name) {
    fHobby.postHobby(description, name);
    return Response.ok("success").build();
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Krak</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Krak</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I can provide any additional info if you'd like

Comment: What is shown for this request in the Network tab of the devtools in your browser? Specifically, what's the method in the headers section?

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but are you sure you're doing a POST request and not a GET on chrome? If you can provide how you make the request on chrome as lealceldeiro said, it'd be helpful.

Comment: How are you doing `POST` in chrome browser?

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error? Check your devtools. Is it an OPTIONS preflight request. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435)

Comment: I have trouble inspecting anything in devtools, since chrome redirects to its default error page before I get to do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you're invoking this simply by inputting the URL in the browser's address bar and hitting enter (I arrived at this conclusion since you're using `@PathParam` which means that you can embed your desired data directly in the URL). This will result in an `HTTP GET`. Your method states that it is an HTTP endpoint that accepts `HTTP POST` requests. Hence the application server will return a `405 Method not allowed` as it does not accept `HTTP GET` requests at that endpoint.

Comment: When commenting the @PathParam out and hardcoding the values I still get a 405

Comment: @JonasGrønbek that's really besides the point. I was just explaining how I concluded that what you're probably doing is simply inserting the URL into the browser's address bar and hitting enter. If that is correct then it explains the behavior as that will result in an `HTTP GET` being fired, not an `HTTP POST`.

Comment: I should have read it more carefully.
Wait, so you're telling me that you cannot run post methods from the browser directly in the URL?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek All I'm saying is that the default behavior when you enter a URL into the address bar and hit enter is that an `HTTP GET` is fired. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107983/is-it-possible-to-do-a-post-request-from-browser-url) will probably be helpful to you.

Comment: I was able to look at the request in IE, and you are right it does not recognize the post. Thanks for your time! Upvoted and marked as accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar with Spring a couple of days ago and I realized that I was typing the endpoint wrong into my browser. If this is an MVC application, check your controller param. Do you have any logging that you can enable?

Comment: If it works successfully in Postman but not in browser then it i safe to assume that the entered url is correct.

Comment: Oh shoot, you're completely correct. I didn't read that correctly. Sorry about that!